# For all continuous function $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, there exists $x_0, x_1 \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_0) \leq f(x) \leq f(x_1) \forall x \in [a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know this is straightforward using the fact that if $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, then $f(X)$ is compact, but I'm struggling to conclude this using the tip given in the book. It says: suppose, for example, that that $x_1$ doesn't exist, then define the function $g(x) = 1/[f(x) - \alpha]$, where $\alpha = \sup f$, and show that this function is continuous and bounded in $[a,b]$

This is the exercise 11, of chapter 2 from this book: https://pt.b-ok.lat/book/5628118/143b6e

Comment: What are you allowed to make use of in the proof? What is the book you're using? That should be helpful information for someone who would like to write a proof for you/give you hints.

Comment: Right, I'm gonna edit.

Comment: What is the problem in using tip?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh intuitively I can see that the function g is continuous because, as $x_1$ doesn't exists, we have that $\alpha \notin f([a,b])$, then $f(x) \neq \alpha$, and then $g$ is continuous. I know that every continuous function from an interval to $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded, and then g is bounded. But as $f(x)$ approaches to $\alpha$, the function explodes, so it can be bounded. I just don't how to formalize it very well.

Comment: You last comment is as formal as it needs to be. Don't overcomplicate. +1 and good job.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just forgot to mention that just continuous functions from closed intervals to $\mathbb{R}$ are certainly bounded. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you know that every continuous function on a compact interval is bounded, then it follows immediately that $g(x) = \frac{1}{\alpha-f(x)}$ (it's nicer to work with this) is bounded (since it is continuous and certainly defined on a compact interval). But now, any $M > 0$, it is certainly true that there exists an $x_M \in [a,b]$ such that:
$$\alpha- f(x_M) \leq \frac{1}{M}$$
But now, it follows that:
$$M \leq g(x_M)$$
So, $g$ is certainly not bounded and that is a contradiction.